# Assume a variable is a Matrix

Tags: matrix, assumptions

Is it possible to tell Mathematica to assume a variable is a matrix, analogous to assuming a variable is real with the `Assuming` command?

Comment: you can use `$Assumptions = 
 m \[Element] Matrices[{d, d}, Reals]]` or `Assuming[m \[Element] Matrices[{d, d}, Reals], ...]`

Comment: I think that such questions can't be answered productively without some context. `Assuming` does not affect every function. The right question is not "how to assume that a symbol is a matrix", but "how to do a certain operation with a symbolic matrix". So, what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: See all the questions on this site along the lines of 
"I set `x` to be real, but Mathematica doesn't treat it as such!". That's because only certain functions take assumptions into account. If the assumption is about tensors, the set of functions that supports them is even more restricted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Matrices](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Matrices.html) can be used as a domain just like `Reals`, `Integers`:

```
$Assumptions = Element[m1 | m2, Matrices[{d, d}, Reals, Symmetric[{1, 2}]]];
TensorDimensions[m1]
```

> {d, d}

```
TensorDimensions[TensorProduct[m1, m2]]
```

> {d, d, d, d}

```
Assuming[Element[v, Matrices[{d, d2}, Reals]], TensorDimensions[m v]]
```

> {d, d2}